# Firefox <form> <select> <option> doesn't show all options

Tags: forms, firefox, select

http://www.clinde.de/easy2/booking/index.php

Works fine in Chrome and Opera, doesn't show all options in Firefox, only first option is displayed. Source is fine imho. Dropdown list is only one option.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Normally, people prefer if you show a small section of code that shows the issue, like something that fits in a JSFiddle. Chances are, if a small section of code doesn't reproduce it, then the issue is bad HTML somewhere else in your document.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8TLGt/2/

Comment: There you go, its on jsfiddle. With firefox the dropdown is only one option where it should be 4.

Comment: Even better jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TLGt/3/

Comment: There must be a problem in the style.css. If i delete that resource everything is fine.

Comment: Yeah, i tracked it down and found the problem.

Comment: One of these must be the troublemaker: 
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;

Comment: display: inline-block; was the problem. Not sure what it does anyway.

Comment: Note that it's okay to provide and accept an Answer to your own question, if you'd like. It might help people who are Googling their own issue someday.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. 
But thanks for that advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (as noted in the comments), `display: inline-block;` creates the issue on the  selector in CSS, only in FireFox. Change to `display: block;` to fix this.